# Angular Social login package 'angularx-social-login' gives error Namespace has no exported member 'eeFactoryDeclaration'

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular9, angular-social-login

We are using Angular 9, and trying to implement package 'angularx-social-login' for social media login. It is installed successfully, but as we are importing classes from package in app.module.ts it gives us error as below:

```
Namespace '"C:/xampp/htdocs/ABC/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'eeFactoryDeclaration'
```

[This is the error which we are getting while implementing angularx-social-login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUv9C.png)

[This code gives an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfHfL.png)

We had already tried:

1. We have updated npm using 'npm update' many times
2. also have tried to implement this separate Angular setup, but still, it is giving the same error.
   Note: On other hand, it's not working on Angular 10 as well, It only works on Angular 12.

Can anyone look at this and help us, please?

Answer (score 0):

Check if Angular 9 is suitable to the package version you installed:
[image]

However, please notice that up to this date, they are all deprecated.

Here is a repository for Google Sign In, using Angular and Google Identity, should be suitable to all Angular versions:
https://github.com/ShemiNechmad/GoogleSignInAngular